# What is the state transition matrix for this time varying system

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, control-theory

> $$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}x_1&=-x_1+\sin(t)x_2 \\
> \frac{d}{dt}x_2&=-t^2x_2\end{align}$$

What is the state transition matrix for these differential equations? How do you get it? Please show me steps. Thank you!

Edit: Thank you kind stranger for helping me with the formatting!

Comment: **Hint:** https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Time_Variant_System_Solutions

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Besides the webpage Moo linked to, are you also familiar with separation of variables?

Comment: Hi @KwinvanderVeen, I have looked at the webpage provided by Moo. I know I need to find the fundamental matrix but I don't know how to handle the t^2 in the second equation. How does separation of variable help?

Comment: @dachou: The equations are decoupled - and you can use Separation of Variables to solve the second equation for $x_2$ and then substitute that into the first equation and solve for $x_1$. We have $$\displaystyle \int~\dfrac{1}{x_2}~dx_2 = -\int t^2~ dt$$

Answer (score 1):

As Moo pointed out the second equation can be solved separately by solving

$$\dfrac{dx_2}{x_2}=-t^2dt\implies \ln x_2 = \ln c_1 -\dfrac{1}{3}t^3 \implies x_2(t)=c_1\exp\left[-t^3/3 \right].$$

Use this for the first equation to obtain:

$$\dfrac{dx_1}{dt}=-x_1+c_1\sin t\exp\left[-t^3/3\right].$$

As far as I can see there is no closed form solution to this ODE. But you can express it using an integral (obtainable by integrating factor or variation of parameters)

$$x_1(t)=c_1\exp (-t)\int_{1}^{t}\exp(\tau - \tau^3/3) \sin \tau d\tau + c_2 \exp(-t).$$

Combining both results we get

$$x_1(t)=c_1\exp (-t)\int_{1}^{t}\exp(\tau - \tau^3/3) \sin \tau d\tau + c_2 \exp(-t)$$
$$x_2(t)=c_1\exp\left[-t^3/3 \right]+c_2\cdot 0.$$

We conclude that the fundamental solution $\boldsymbol{X}(t)$ is given as

$$\boldsymbol{X}(t)=\begin{bmatrix}
\exp (-t)\int_{1}^{t}\exp(\tau - \tau^3/3) \sin \tau d\tau & \exp(-t)\\
\exp\left[-t^3/3 \right] & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

In order to derive the state transition matrix $\boldsymbol{\Phi}(t,t')$ we need to calculate

$$ \boldsymbol{\Phi}(t,t') = \boldsymbol{X}(t)\boldsymbol{X}^{-1}(t').$$

---

Remark: In order to invert an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ you can use the following formula

$$\boldsymbol{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix} \implies \boldsymbol{A}^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{\det \boldsymbol{A}}\begin{bmatrix}
a_{22} & -a_{12}\\
-a_{21} & a_{11}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

If you would like to see another example you can also have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2491980/262304).